# PSQL select & replace chars

Tags: psql

How do I select from both tables based on the Name from different menus but the data is almost identical in PSQL?
I've tried using the select and replace from psql command.

```
SELECT * FROM americanmenu JOIN europeanmenu ON replace(usmenu.type, \'US\', \'EU\') = eumenu.type WHERE usmenu.type = eumenu.type
```

*table US*

> ```
> ID | type | year  
> ----------------------
> 01 |  wine 1 us |  2001  
> 02 | wine 2  us | 2002
> ```

*table EU*

> ```
> ID | TYPE | year
> --------------------
> 01 | wine 1 eu | 2001  
> 02 | wine 2 eu | 2002
> ```

There is are additional columns for price and taste ratings which I did not include because this is the gist of the problem. I would want to select from the us table by type, and replacing the last 2 characters/string into "eu" and be able to compare both tables even though there is alot of identical data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
t=# SELECT *
FROM americanmenu a
JOIN europeanmenu e ON replace(a.type, 'us','eu') = e.type;
 id  |    type     | year | id  |    type     | year
-----+-------------+------+-----+-------------+------
 01  |  wine 1 us  | 2001 | 01  |  wine 1 eu  | 2001
 02  |  wine 2 us  | 2002 | 02  |  wine 2 eu  | 2002
(2 rows)

Time: 0.297 ms
```

prepare:

```
t=# create table americanmenu (id text, type text, year int);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 4.515 ms
t=# create table europeanmenu (id text, type text, year int);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 15.218 ms
t=# copy americanmenu from stdin delimiter '|';
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> 01 | wine 1 us | 2001
02 | wine 2 us | 2002>>
>> \.
COPY 2
Time: 7144.563 ms
t=# copy europeanmenu from stdin delimiter '|';
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> 01 | wine 1 eu | 2001
02 | wine 2 eu | 2002>>
>> \.
COPY 2
Time: 9729.000 ms
```